# How do you read children firebase with another children (hashMap)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I create the class java for read the User with the basic values (chatAvailable, dateCreate, email, fullname) but in this class I need read **datos** for this user. Datos is a children dynamic can be have more children (genero, naf, many others...).

On iOS I can read this with NSDictionary and obtain children in **datos** with successful, but in Android I can't solve this.

[image: I read user with class, but I can't read child datos]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("datos");
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                switch(childDataSnapshot.getKey()){
                  case "genero":
                  //get your data with childDataSnapshot.child("value").getValue(String.class);
                  break;
                  case "naf":
                  break;
                  //more cases according possible childs
                }
            }

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
});
```